# Media query not applying to large mobile devices (tablets)

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I've got some media queries that aren't working correctly for me, basically the css below is supposed to show some elements on desktop and some elements on mobiles.

For example, hiding some "hover" elements on mobiles/tablets but making them visible on desktop devices.

```
@media (max-width: 1024px){
    .desktop_only {
       display: none !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1025px){
    .mobile_only {
       display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Granted in CSS4, we will be able to do this much easier using the 'pointer' feature: https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/#pointer but I can't use that because that's the future, not yet implemented.

I tried using:

```
<script>
    document.documentElement.className += 
    (("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) ? ' touch' : ' no-touch');
</script>
```

I've tried using Modernizer too, which is supposed to also add the touch/no-touch

With:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px){
    .touch .desktop_only {
       display: none !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1025px){
    .no-touch .mobile_only {
       display: none !important;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, it's not hiding elements correctly. I've also tried them without the `@media (xxxx: 102x)` part but that doesn't work either. I've also tried switching touch and no-touch over just in case I had them wrong.

I can't use the css: `-moz-system-metric(touch-enabled)` as it's not supported by many browsers

Unsure how I can use http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ to do what I want

Anyone have any clues what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `@media only screen and (max-width:1025px)` as well as including `<meta name="viewport" width=device-width">` in the `<head>` somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried validating your CSS?  Sometimes a missing bracket somewhere in the previous elements can mess up whatever code is underneath it.

Comment: @Brian css is all valid, I've tried that css across multiple areas of the page, it doesn't work still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basiclly your medias are wrong, See min-width and max-width, do this

```
.mobile-only {
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px){
  .desktop-only {
    display: block;
  }
  .mobile-only {
    display: none;
  }
  .desktop-only:hover {
    color:#000;
  }
}
```

don't use underscores

Edit - here is mine

```
/* ===============
 DISPLAY SETTINGS
 =============== */

@media all and (max-width: 43.688em) { /* 489px */

    .mobile-is-hidden { display: none; }

}

@media all and (min-width: 43.688em) and (max-width: 61.188em) { /* 699px to 979px */

    .pad-is-hidden { display: none; }

}

@media all and (min-width: 61.250em) { /* 980px */

    .desk-is-hidden { display: none; }

}
```

Comment: Hi, that still doesn't work. It's not applying it to a Nexus 10 landscape for example.

Comment: @Ryflex this is just an example, You have to find out the actual screen size and even then if the phone has retina this plays on it also. for example mobile-is-hidden only works on screen sizes up to a width of 489px, If you want it hidden on landscape also this will cause issues with tablets as a lot of the time they use the same width. (most people dont use landscape on mobiles for websites as this is annoying to do)